楽天API x Python を使って商品の値段を自動で変更できるようにするのに必要なもの
販売者の立場で、楽天API x Python を使って商品の値段を自動で変更できるようにするのに必要なものは何でしょうか。
楽天のアカウント情報など、必要なものを手当たり次第教えてもらいたいです。

ここでの「値段を変更」は販売者側ということでしょうか？

場合によっては既に実績のありそうなこんな人に相談するといった方法も考えられますね。楽天APIを利用したツールを作成します API連携で価格・在庫変更の自動化プログラム作成します。

はい、販売者側になります。
質問に情報が不足していてすみません

こちらが参考になるかと思います。
Rakuten Developers Introduction
